# No sound on Ubuntu 16.04 with Intel Skylake chipset

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, hda-intel

I have now spent several months on and off trying to get any sound out of my new HP Envy AIO. Hardware is OK, works fine under Windows 10 dual boot.

I had originally installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, then upgraded the kernel to 4.4, and then upgraded the whole system to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

lspci gives:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
    DeviceName: Onboard Audio
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 143
    Memory at df520000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at df500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

aplay -l gives:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20753/4 Analog [CX20753/4 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

dmesg contains:

```
[   11.521966] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0100 -> 0102)
[   11.522088] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915_bpo])
[   12.015525] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: CX20753/4: BIOS auto-probing.
[   12.016376] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for CX20753/4: line_outs=1 (0x1d/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   12.016378] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   12.016379] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x16/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   12.016380] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   12.016381] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   12.016382] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x1a
[   12.016383] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[   12.017769] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: Enable sync_write for stable communication
[159427.084801] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: IRQ timing workaround is activated for card #0. Suggest a bigger bdl_pos_adj.
```

I have tried tricks like jack-retask but whatever I do - no sound, neither on the speakers nor in headphones.

Of course the levels in alsa-mixer have been set. I have tried several options in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

No sound whatever I do.

What is going on here? And what can I do to get sound? I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just spent hours solving a similar sound problem on my machine:

Answered Here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1019666/322860

Comment: I had tried DKMS and updated drivers from https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Turns out this happened to me again and I could not get the Sound Cards to list using `aplay -l`. I ended up reinstalling a fresh Ubuntu :( DAMN SOUND MODULES!!!

Comment: I don't think a fresh installation will cure the problem. I think it must be some sort of racing problem where some hardware detection depends on what happens at the same time and possibly faster. Unfortunately I am not the sort of person who could do that sort of kernel programming.

Comment: Possibly hardware, but I think the problem began after an Update, not exactly sure which one, I did have `unsupported updates` on which may have contributed.... All I know is that sound worked for the last year, and has been working for the past week on the reinstalled System....

Comment: Then you definitely have a different problem to the one I am having on my machine where sound hasn't ever worked under Linux.