# Ubuntu 17.04 - dummy output

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hda-intel

I installed ubuntu 17.04 and i have no sound

```
aplay -l
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...

/0/100/1f.3               multimedia     200 Series PCH HD Audio
with lshw command
```

and I tryed everything that i found on google(ala base config; reinstaling alsa; reinstaling kernel) but still no sound

Please help me if u have any idea!

Comment: did you have sound ?  does booting from the LiveCD give you sound ? ... sometime installing wrong packages or source will break sound

Comment: i have linux mint 18.1 installed and everything worked fine. But suddenly sound stopped. I tried everything like i said, and than decided to install ubuntu 17.04, in order to resolve my problem. But that didnt happen.  Booting from CD- still no sound :/

Comment: The benefit of booting from any LiveCD is that its a known good combination of libraries ... if its OK using LiveCD then the hardware plays nicely with the software ... two things :  try to boot using mint 18.1 LiveCD ... if bad then in that same boot up issue above aplay -l command ... if still no then I would resort to opening up your computer and removing then putting back in your sound card as possibly that board just needs to get re-seated ... if still bad then its possibly just a bad sound card

Answer (score 1):

First go to terminal 
Next type in sudo apt install hwinfo
After its installed type in hwinfo 
Find "Hardware Class:Sound"
When you find it check if the driver is active
Finally use modprone command in my computer is "modprone snd_hda_intel"
The hwinfo should look like this:

```
19: PCI 14.2: 0403 Audio device
  [Created at pci.378]
  Unique ID: 5Dex.uwrfjAf9Rl0
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:14.2
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)"
  Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
  Device: pci 0x4383 "SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)"
  SubVendor: pci 0x103c "Hewlett-Packard Company"
  SubDevice: pci 0x2ab7 
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xfe8f0000-0xfe8f3fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 16 (3729 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001002d00004383sv0000103Csd00002AB7bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

For future people,

I was able to reinstall my **HDA Intel** sound driver using the following commands:

**1. Make sure the intel hda package is installed**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
```

**2. Remove current sound driver**

*Find version xxxxxxx using:*

```
ls /usr/src/ | grep audio
```

Remove sound driver

```
sudo dkms remove oem-audio-hda-daily/xxxxxxx~ubuntu17.10.1 --all
```

**3. Reinstall driver**

```
sudo dkms install oem-audio-hda-daily/xxxxxxx~ubuntu17.10.1
```

Reboot computer, and at least `aplay -l` shows some devices now

**4. Youtube Doesn't Sound Right?**

This is weird, but when using headphones, you might experience bad sound quality when viewing youtube videos.

To fix: go to Sound Settings, and set the balance all the way to one side. Weird but it worked on my machine.

Got this answer here: [Audio not working properly with reverb & underwater sounds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005422/audio-not-working-properly-with-reverb-underwater-sounds)