# Audio not working properly with reverb & underwater sounds

Tags: sound, xubuntu, 17.10, pulseaudio, alsa

My pc is a somewhat old Lenovo Ideacenter K410 tower. It originally came with Win7 preloaded. I updated the OS to Xubuntu 16.04 LTS and have been using that for 2+ years, but have JUST RECENTLY updated to 17.10.1. I tried using a USB audio interface, and each time I plugged it in, it seemed to freeze all audio on my pc. I tried rebooting with the device plugged in and with it unplugged, with the exact same frozen audio result. So I tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo start-pulseaudio-x11 start
```

None of that seemed to fix the audio issues. Now the audio seems to work barely, but with what sounds like **Reverb always on, or maybe surround sound always on.** I can't hear an mp3 song file fully - I hear the guitars, drums, but the singer sounds like they're on a different channel. Youtube playback sounds like it's underwater, with gurgling water sounds. It's really strange.

Ergo, why I upgraded to Xubuntu 17.10.1, I thought upgrading to a newer version would fix said audio issues. IT DIDN'T. The audio is still acting the same way.

I mostly use a 2-channel headphone plugged into the front, but have 5.1 audio output on the back from the motherboard that I rarely ever use.

Here is the output using the following terminal commands:

```
$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC662 rev3 Analog [ALC662 rev3 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
---------------------------

$ sudo lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
---------------------------

$ cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.13.0-32-generic.
--------------------------

$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC662 rev3
Codec: Intel CougarPoint HDMI
-------------------------

$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7d00000 irq 30
 1 [U0x46d0x9a4    ]: USB-Audio - USB Device 0x46d:0x9a4
                      USB Device 0x46d:0x9a4 at usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4, high speed
-------------------------

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0480:0212 Toshiba America Inc 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0184 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5182 Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:09a4 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam E 3500
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0764:0501 Cyber Power System, Inc. CP1500 AVR UPS
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
-------------------------

$ pactl list short sources
0   alsa_input.usb-046d_09a4_1D90F520-02.analog-mono    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 16000Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
-------------------------

$ pactl list short sinks
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
-------------------------

$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9959
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC662 rev3 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC662 rev3 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7d00000 irq 30"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1c20"
        device.product.name = "6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC662 rev3"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0662,17aa3653,00100300 HDA:80862805,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:

        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-headphones>
---------------------------------
```

Any help is always graciously & humbly received. Since using Xubuntu exclusively for the past 2+ years, I really couldn't have kept at it without AskUbuntu's help. Thank you all for all the answers over the years.

**So. What's up with my audio? Why am I hearing what sounds like Reverb with everything played?** I have NOT added any sort of audio effects.

I am considering editing the following file, based on the instructions provided here:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1043568

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
# add at the very bottom of the page 
options snd-hda-intel model=lenovo-3000 position_fix=1
```

I'll post an update if this fixes the problem.

---

UPDATE (1-2018):

1. I applied the following edit:
2. sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
3. << add at the very bottom of the page >>
4. options snd-hda-intel model=lenovo 3stack-6ch-dig position_fix=1

I discovered if I adjust the BALANCE (using GNOME Alsa Mixer or Qasmixer) all the way RIGHT or LEFT, **the audio sounds correct & centered, and the reverb & underwater effect goes away, even Youtube videos sound correct.**

Not sure if this Update is the proverbial FIX. I mean, why would I need to adjust the BALANCE all the way RIGHT or LEFT?

NEW UPDATE (2-2018):

I just discovered the audio works great with the headphones ONLY, But **only the left channel works with the pc speakers. The right channel is completely dead using the pc speakers.**

Comment: sounds like reverb or underwater and presumably no such effects have been added to audio chain? delay effect is possibly caused by audio playback being mixed from 2 different sources with one slightly delayed

Comment: no such effects have been added. So, what you @nik gnomic are saying is, that (possibly) PulseAudio & ALSA are mixing the same audio source at the same time, but with one apparently exhibiting some audio latency? ergo the reverb effect?

Comment: have recently learned how to update ALSA (ONLY if needed), by following instructions given here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

Comment: Considering uninstalling PulseAudio and using ALSA exclusively, using instructions here -
https://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/how-to-remove-pulseaudio-use-alsa-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: mixing 2 sources with different delay is how reverb effect is created. if no effects in use an audio routing problem is the only likely conclusion. eliminate one of the 2 sources and reverb will stop. is the usb device shown a webcam? try unplugging it and see if reverb stops.

Comment: yes it's a webcam. BUT there's an UPDATE to all this: I discovered if I adjust the balance all the way RIGHT or LEFT (using either GNOME Alsa Mixer or QASmixer), the audio sounds correct & in the center and the reverb & underwater effects go away. And youtube videos play back correctly too.